# TinyMCE 4.1.6 editor does not appear in Chrome sometimes

Tags: google-chrome, ruby-on-rails-4, tinymce-4

I found that sometimes tinymce editor in my rails webapp does not appear when using Chrome automatically. When this happens I have to refresh the page to make it appear. IE and firefox do not have such problem. Any idea?

I am using no plugins and tried to firebug the problem (like in here http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=16402) but get no results. I am using the custom skin *light*.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you are using `'tinymce-rails'`. I had a similar problem and it is related to turbolinks. Te way I solved it was:

1. Make sure that tiny-mce assets are loaded by your page by adding `<%= tinymce_assets %>` to your application layout.
2. Remove and init tiny-mce on `$(document).ready` and `'page:load'` on the page where you want to use it.

   ```
   function initTinyMCE() {
       tinymce.remove();
       tinymce.init({
           selector: '<your-selector>',
           skin: 'lightgray'
       });
   }

   $(document).ready(function () {
       initTinyMCE()
   });
   document.addEventListener('page:load', function () {
       initTinyMCE()
   });
   ```

That works for me. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, it looks promising but does not works for me. TinyMCE now does not load at all. I'll keep trying.

Comment: I've seen this in the tinymce-rails github page; "Ensure that you explicitly require tinymce-rails within your engine file. Including tinymce-rails as a dependency in your gemspec is not enough." Could it be related? I don't see any engine file anyway...

Answer (score 1):

The problem was related to turbolinks, I tried to disable it for tinymce textarea but it dind't work. Finally, I disabled completely turbolink for all the site:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => false %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => false %>
```

and in the body tag `<body data-no-turbolink>`

This solved the problem mentioned.

Additionally, since the turbolinks is disabled the performance of the site has improved, specifically I don't see any *Flash of unstyled content* which was other problem I have in the app.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help. Your example works for me on PHP.

I just do this way bellow.

```
tinymce.remove();

setTimeout(function () {
    tinymce.init({selector: '#textarea'});
}, 2000);
```

I had to add a setTimeout() method because directly don't work.

Every time that I have to change the value on text-area I called this method again to load the component.